# Android webview using html+jquery inside app hangs sometimes

Tags: java, android, jquery, webview, fabricjs

i had made html+jquery mobile app using webview , my all code is inside assest folder, i noticed sometime my app hangs and sometime it works fine ,if i am missing some thing

below is android java code

i made html +jquery app , app hangs most of time , and some time it works any way to make it work fine

below problem:

1: some time object in canvas gets duplicated however there is not changes of getting duplicate object on any of canvas this problem occurs only in android browser

2: sometime while dragging object gets stuck any where without being dropped in canvas only in android browser
below is my java code for that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        });
        refreshWebView();
    }

    private void refreshWebView() {
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        refreshWebView();
    }

}
```

and html code that i am using inside assest folde is below link

http://liveweave.com/JckSgC

Answer (score 0):

I faced this bug before 6 months ago. After a lot lot of research on this topic I personally concluded that *Its a API bug of android* which was fixed in API level 18(KITKAT).

It means, "*If the application is working on an android version less than Kitkat, webview starts hanging or works madly*"

### Reason:

- WebView's of android version less than KITKAT doesn't support HTML5 and CSS3.
  http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview

### Suggestions:

- You can use external webviews like "ChromiumWebView"
  (Link of ChromiumWebView https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview )
- Or you can restrict your application to only runs on android version greater than or equivalent to KITKAT. (I personally doesn't prefer this)